# Programmatically discard changes in DataForm

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit, dataform

I have a DataForm from System.Windows.Controls.Data.DataForm.Toolkit and I need to programmatically get the same result as after clicking Cancel on this DataForm.

I need that because this DataForm is in ChildWindow, and if I change something in DataForm and I close a ChildWindow, then changes will be commited. This shouldn't work in that way.
When I close ChildWindow I want to discard all changes the same as after clicking Cancel Button.

I've tried

```
protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    dfColumnInfo.CancelEdit();

    base.OnClosing(e);
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Thank you in advance.

bugfinder suggested to add a code which saves changes.
There is no such thing, because childWindow has an editedObject as a DataContext

```
childWindow.DataContext = table;
childWindow.MyDataForm.DataContext = table.Items;
childWindow.Show();
```

I don't know how how, but Cancel button of DataForm reverts all changes which I've done in DataForm, which is a great think. 
But how to get the same effect by using some other button of childWindow, or just by closing childWindow?

Comment: Can you show how and when you call your saving code - its likely its done before you get to the onclosing

Comment: Thought #2 Do you have autocommit set to true?

Answer (score 0):

I searched for you,
and found some useful stuff here:
http://forums.silverlight.net/t/112449.aspx/1

Then tested like this:

```
void dform_EditEnded(object sender, DataFormEditEndedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.EditAction != DataFormEditAction.Commit)
    {
        (dform.CurrentItem as MyEntity).RejectChanges();
        return;
    }
}
```

To achieve this goal the MyEntity must be public as I coded its partial below.
I'm sharing word from silverlightnet forum **"To be able to call RejectChanges (which is a protected method of the System.Windows.Ria.Entity class, we have to make it public"**

```
public partial class MyEntity:Entity
{
   public void RejectChanges()
   {
       if (HasChanges)
           base.RejectChanges();
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.